# Linear transformation in $\mathcal{P}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathcal{P}\rightarrow \mathcal{P}$ be the function that maps each polynomial to its derivative

$$T(f)=f'$$

Let $S:\mathcal{P}\rightarrow \mathcal{P}$ be the function that multiplies its input polynomial by $x$.
$$S(f)=g \ \ \ \ \textrm{where} \ \ \ \ \ g=xf(x)$$

What I want to do is prove that they are both linear transformations, find $\textrm{ker}\ T$, $\textrm{ker}\ S$ and $\textrm{im}\ T$, $\textrm{im} \ S$. Determine whether they are injective and/or surjective and what $(T\circ S)-(S\circ T)$ does.

Proving that they are linear transformations by itself is easy by just utilizing the basic properties of differentiation, however finding the Kernel and Image aren't as easy for me.

$T$ I am thinking that $$p_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k a_nx^n $$

Which gives $$\frac{d}{dx}p_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k na_nx^{n-1}$$
So $p_n(x)$ is spanned by $\{x^n,x^{n-1},x^{n-1},\cdots ,1\}$ where the image is spanned by $\{x^{n-1},x^{n-2},\cdots 1\}$

For $S$ I am completely lost. I know how to compute $(T\circ S)-(S\circ T)$  when I have a concrete matrix, but it becomes much harder to visualize how I do it in $\mathcal{P}$. Just for clarity, $\mathcal{P}$ is the vector space of all polynomials of an aribtrary degree. If someone could show me how it is done, and how to approach it I think I would learn a lot.

While I am at it, how would I do the exact same things for $T$ if it was from $T:\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})? $

Comment: @user744868: Say what?

Comment: @TedShifrin have you got any ideas on $\mathcal{C}^\infty (\mathbb{R})$? Proving that it is a linear transformation is almost trivial. When trying to find the kernel of T I figured it had to be all functions mapping to 0, i.e. all constant functions such that $\textrm{Ker} \ T=\{f\in \mathcal{C}^\infty (\mathbb{R})|f'=0\}$. Which would be the number line. I don't know if I'm just stupid or tired, but I can't figure whether it's finite dimensional and surjective. Got any pointers? I see you're pretty active in diff. geom/lin. alg. A hint tells me to use the fundamental theorem, but I dunno how.

Comment: You don't have a basis for the space, but you still know calculus.  $\ker T$ is the subspace of all constant functions [not "the number line"]. You need to be thinking about calculus. Is every $C^\infty$ function the derivative of some $C^\infty$ function?

Comment: I don't know if I'm thinking completely wrong, but wouldn't it have to be?

Comment: So how do you explicitly write down a function $g(x)$ with $g'(x)=f(x)$?

Comment: $g(x)=\int_a^x f'(t)dt$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$T(S(f)) (x)-S(T(f))(x)=(xf(x))'-xf'(x)=[xf'(x)+f(x)]-xf'(x)=f(x)$. So $T \circ S-S \circ T$ is the identity function $f \to f$.

$T$ is surjective but not injective. $S$ is injective but not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

The only functions from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ whose derivative is the null function are the constant functions. Therefore, $\ker T$ is the set of all constant polynomials.

On the other hand, every polynomial function has a primitive which is also a polynomial function. Therefore, $T$ is surjective.

And, clearly, $S$ is injective. In other words, $\ker S=\{0\}$.

Finally,\begin{align}T\bigl(S\bigl(P(x)\bigr)\bigr)-S\bigl(T\bigl(P(x)\bigr)\bigr)&=T\bigl(xP(x)\bigr)-S\bigl(P'(x)\bigr)\\&=xP'(x)+P(x)-xP'(x)\\&=P(x).\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$Ker(S)=\{f \in \mathscr{P}: xf(x)=0\}$$ So if $f\in Ker(S)$ then $xf(x)=0$ the zero polynomial hence $f$ must have been the zero polynomial to begin with so $Ker(S)=0$ and S is injective.

S cannot be surjective since the constant polynomials do not lie in its range.

Answer (score 0):

$\textrm{ker}\ T$ is the set of Polynomials whose derivative is $0$, i.e. constant polynomials.

$\textrm{im}\ T$ is the set of Polynomials which are the derivatives of some other polynomials, which is $\mathcal{P}$ because each polynomial is the image of its primitive.

$\textrm{ker}\ S$ is $0$, because $xf(x) = 0 \implies \sum_{n=0}^k a_n x^{n+1} = 0 \implies a_n = 0$ for all n.

$\textrm{im}\ S$ is simply $x.\mathcal{P}$.

$(ToS - SoT)(P) = (XP)' - XP' = P \implies ToS - SoT = Id$